# how to redirect /app/webroot/bolg/wp-admin to blog/wp-admin, .htacsess is not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp

I have change /app/webroot/blog/.htacsess to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/webroot/blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /app/webroot/blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and root /.htacsess to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RedirectMatch temp ^/blog/wp-admin$ http://mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/
    RewriteRule blog$ /blog/ [L]
    RewriteRule blog/wp-admin$ /blog/wp-admin/ [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

my site is redirect to http://mysite.com/blog/ but when I try lo login into admin site like http://mysite.com/blog/wp-admin it redirect to http://mysite.com/app/webroot/blog/wp-admin and my username and password is not working.

but if I write hardcode url "http://mysite.com/blog/wp-login.php" then my username and password is working.

How to solve this problem? please help me...

Comment: go to http://domain.com/wp-admin/options-general.php after login into dashboard and make sure Site Address (URL) is same as WordPress Address (URL) .

Comment: I changed both URL to http://mysite.com/blog/

Comment: no.; when I try this link http://mysite.com/blog/ it open. but when I try http://mysite.com/blog/wp-admin it redirect to http://mysite.com/app/webroot/blog/wp-admin. and my username and password is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `app/webroot/blog/.htaccess` should be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /blog/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Your base `.htaccess` should be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RedirectMatch temp ^/blog/wp-admin$ http://www.yoursite.com/blog/wp-admin/
   RewriteRule blog$ /blog/ [L]
   RewriteRule blog/wp-admin$ /blog/wp-admin/ [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ /app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Notice the **/**'s in the RewriteRules:

```
RewriteRule    ^$ /app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
```